# What is the proper way to include a link to a web archiving site in a list of references?

Tags: citations

This is a reference in a list of references presented in Harvard style:

Beard, M. (2003). Non-terrestrial channels overtake BBC1 and ITV1 in ratings for first time. *The Independent*. [online] Available at: http://www.independent.co.uk/news/media/non-terrestrial-channels-overtake-bbc1-and-itv1-in-ratings-for-first-time-116550.html [Accessed 18 May 2017].

Here is a perma.cc archival link to that reference:

https://perma.cc/9TR9-WBRG

What is the proper way to incorporate the archival URL into the citation in the list of references?

Answer (score 1):

You could write

> Beard, M. (2003). Non-terrestrial channels overtake BBC1 and ITV1 in ratings for first time. The Independent. [online] Available at: http://www.independent.co.uk/news/media/non-terrestrial-channels-overtake-bbc1-and-itv1-in-ratings-for-first-time-116550.html [Accessed 18 May 2017]. **(Archived at https://perma.cc/9TR9-WBRG.)**

Or, you could use an archive site that includes the original URL, e.g.,

> Beard, M. (2003). Non-terrestrial channels overtake BBC1 and ITV1 in ratings for first time. The Independent. [online] **Available at: https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.independent.co.uk/news/media/non-terrestrial-channels-overtake-bbc1-and-itv1-in-ratings-for-first-time-116550.html** [Accessed 18 May 2017].

I favour this instance, because you only need to include one URL. (The original URL is clear from the archived URL.)

Comment: In example 1, would the period go inside the paranthesis or outside?

Comment: Inside. See http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/periods-and-parentheses

Comment: Typical grammar rules presumably wouldn't apply to a bibliography entry, or else we wouldn't place a period at the end of all titles and all proper titles? Are the examples you provided above generally accepted use of archival websites or just something you personally use / created?

Comment: Example 2 is standard, in the sense that it *is* in Harvard style. Example 1 treats the archived copy as *additional information*, which teaches us to use parenthesis, so again, I believe it is Harvard style.